# Interprolog and SWI-Prolog

Tags: java, linux, prolog, interprolog

I have set up and installed both interprolog and swi prolog on my linux machine following the instructions here :[Interprolog with SWI instructions on Linux](http://www.declarativa.com/interprolog/INSTALL.htm)

I have edited the unixVariables.sh to contain the path of java and swi-prolog(pl) executables on my machine and that my unixVariables.sh looks like:

```
# This is a typical environment for Linux, see elsewhere for Mac OS X
 JAVA_BIN=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.16/bin
 XSB_BIN_DIRECTORY=/home/YOUR_NAME/XSB271/config/i686-pc-linux-gnu/bin
 SWI_BIN_DIRECTORY=/usr/local/bin
 YAP_BIN_DIRECTORY=/usr/bin
```

Now when I go to do ./runSWISPListener.sh in the interprolog folder, all i get is this:

```
./runSWISPListener.sh 
Welcome xx to InterProlog 2.1.2 on Java 1.6.0_16 (Sun Microsystems Inc.), Linux       2.6.28-11-generic
```

and now nothing else happens, where as according to the instructions a java window should popup with a swiprolog engine listener.

can anyone help me? I know its quite abstract and no one really uses interprolog but any help is appreciated
 thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up just using XSB prolog, worked fine

Answer (score 1):

SWI-Prolog and Yap Prolog support JPL (Java-to-Prolog interface); you may want to use it: http://www.swi-prolog.org/packages/jpl/java_api/index.html

Answer (score 0):

According to the download page, InterProlog has known issues with SWI-Prolog Version 5.10:

> (5.4.6 or later; known problems with 5.10 :-( );

(from http://www.declarativa.com/interprolog/INSTALL.htm)

Try an earlier version of SWI-Prolog?